# C# Winforms | Form-border thickness

Tags: c#, winforms, size, border, formborderstyle

Is there any documentation of how thick a border of a regular form is?

**The goal:**
I've created a userControl with a width of 800px. I want to raise a popup (normal form in general) with a new instance of it at full resolution (800px - everything visible).

**My Problem:**
Setting the form to `Form.Size.Width = 800` wont do it. It looks like the border of the form is included in the width-property of the form. I need to subtract that border.

*I should be something like:* 2px + 800px + 2px

If you would like to see some code tell me, but I think its unnecessary in here.

**EDIT**:

[image]

After popping the control up:

[image]

**Code for popup:**

```
private void buttonPopup_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form MyPopup = new Form();
    customControl MyUserControl = new customControl();

    MyUserControl.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

    Rectangle rc = MyUserControl.RectangleToScreen(MyUserControl.ClientRectangle);

    //int thickness = SystemInformation.Border3DSize.Width;
    //MyPopup.MaximumSize = new Size(MyUserControl.Size.Width + (thickness*2), 1500);

    MyPopup.Controls.Add(MyUserControl);
    MyPopup.MaximumSize = new Size(rc.Width, rc.Height);
    MyPopup.Show();
}
```

I mean your code looks logical to me. But still the result is the same. The `userControl` is displayed a tiny bit smaller. I know I've used `dock = fill` where my button isnt placed professionally inside the layout. But away from this there has to be a solution to just **set the right size**.

Comment: Have a look at `SystemInformation` class and `ClientRectangle` property

Comment: It seems that you have to set `ClientSize` (size of the form *excluding* borders, caption etc). `MyPopUp.ClientSize = new Size(...);` instead of `MaximumSize`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that your are looking for

```
int thickness = SystemInformation.Border3DSize;
```

another (and, INHO, a *better* one) possiblity is to use `ClientRectangle` of the control. For instance:

```
// Client rectangle in screen coordinates
Rectangle rc = MyControl.RectangleToScreen(MyControl.ClientRectangle);

// Let's align context menu (its width) to bottom of the control
MyContextMenuStrip.AutoSize = false;
// Depending on actual dropdown control you may want align either via
//   Width = rc.Width;
// Or 
//   ClientSize = new Size(rc.Width, someHeight);
MyContextMenuStrip.Width = rc.Width;

// Let's show context menu at the bottom of the control
MyContextMenuStrip.Show(new Point(rc.Left, rc.Bottom));
```

Comment: For the thickness: Debugging shows up 2 pixels for `width` and `height` of `Border3DSize`. I guess this values are a little bit too small. Ill check out the `ClientRectangle`.

Comment: @C4ud3x: yes, `ClientRectangle` (especially for *user defined* controls) is a *better* way: your control could be, say, *flat* etc.

Comment: Just to stay on the same idea: I dont care about the position of my popup. I just care about the correct size so it fits my userControl. Ill add 2 screenshots. Easier to see then.

Comment: In that case `rc.Width` and `rc.Height` are at your service

Comment: Added 2 screens (before - after). With your `rc.Width` and `rc.Height` I get the same result as in my edit. Ill paste my code also. Possibly I made the mistake somewhere else.

Comment: It seems that you have to set `ClientSize` (size of the control/form *excluding* its *borders*, *caption*, *scrollers* etc). `MyPopUp.ClientSize = new Size(...)`; instead of `MaximumSize`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87458/discussion-between-dmitry-bychenko-and-c4ud3x).

Comment: No need, thats it! Add your `ClientSize`-Info to your answer. Ill mark it then :) It fits perfectly now.